# animate text so letters loop in a circle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a text box which contains the letters ABC.

What I would like to do is have the letters circulate. So going clockwise C would be the first letter to start the circle then as C is part way around the B would start to circulate, then A. When C get to the top I would like it to breifly stop till B & then A get back so we have ABC again. Then repeat - hopefully that makes sense.

My code (mostly copied) is below. Currently all that happens is the C does a circle then stops & then goes again but A & B do not appear to move

C#

```
void StartTextAnimations(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtABC.TextEffects = new TextEffectCollection();

        Storyboard sbRotate = new Storyboard();
        sbRotate.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        sbRotate.AutoReverse = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < txtABC.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            AddTextEffectForCharacter(i);
            AddRotationAnimation(sbRotate, i);
        }

        Timeline pause = FindResource("CharacterRotationPauseAnimation") as Timeline;
        sbRotate.Children.Add(pause);

        sbRotate.Begin(this);            
    }

    void AddTextEffectForCharacter(int charIndex)
    {
        TextEffect effect = new TextEffect();

        effect.PositionStart = charIndex;
        effect.PositionCount = 1;

        TransformGroup transGrp = new TransformGroup();
        transGrp.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform());
        transGrp.Children.Add(new RotateTransform());
        effect.Transform = transGrp;

        txtABC.TextEffects.Add(effect);
    }

    void AddRotationAnimation(Storyboard sbRotate, int charIndex)
    {
        DoubleAnimation anim = FindResource("CharacterRotationAnimation") as DoubleAnimation;

        SetBeginTime(anim, charIndex);

        string path = string.Format("TextEffects[{0}].Transform.Children[1].Angle", charIndex);

        PropertyPath propPath = new PropertyPath(path);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, propPath);

        sbRotate.Children.Add(anim);
    }

    void SetBeginTime(Timeline anim, int charIndex)
    {
        double totalMs = anim.Duration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
        double offset = totalMs / 10;
        double resolvedOffset = offset * charIndex;
        anim.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(resolvedOffset);
    }
```

XAML

```
    <DoubleAnimation
        x:Key="CharacterRotationAnimation"
        To="360"
        AccelerationRatio="0.5"
        DecelerationRatio="0.5"
        Duration="0:0:2"
        Storyboard.TargetName="txtABC"/>

    <DoubleAnimation
        x:Key="CharacterRotationPauseAnimation"
        Duration="0:0:8"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>        
</RibbonWindow.Resources>


<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10"
                x:Name="txtABC"
                Foreground="WhiteSmoke"
                Loaded="StartTextAnimations"
                Text="ABC"/>
```

Comment: Have you played with Path Animation yet?

Comment: No - to be honest I've not heard off that. Never used animation so forgive my ignorance. I'll google it now

Comment: No worries man, that's why SO exists. Sounds like it could make life easier for you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're taking the same double animation every time you use `FindResource` and just changing it's properties in reality.  What you meant to do was apply an effect to each character, meaning each character needs its own instance of `DoubleAnimation`.  Here is the working example I used (changed the foreground so I could actually see the dang thing ;)).

- In `StartTextAnimations`:  Change your for-loop so you begin applying animations in the correct order, starting with "c":

  ```
  //Reverse order applied
  for(int i = txtABC.Text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
      AddTextEffectForCharacter(i);
      AddRotationAnimation(sbRotate, i);
  }
  ```
- Change `AddRotationAnimation` to apply animation to each character:

  ```
  void AddRotationAnimation(Storyboard sbRotate, int charIndex)
  {
      DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(0, 360, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3))); //0 to 360 over 3 seconds
      Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim, "txtABC"); 
      SetBeginTime(anim, charIndex);

      string path = string.Format("TextEffects[{0}].Transform.Children[1].Angle", charIndex);

      PropertyPath propPath = new PropertyPath(path);

      Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, propPath);

      sbRotate.Children.Add(anim);
  }
  ```
- Change your calculations in `SetBeginTime` so that characters don't overlap each other,

  ```
  void SetBeginTime(Timeline anim, int charIndex)
  {
      double totalMs = anim.Duration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
      double offset = totalMs / 4.2; //slow, it, down.
      double resolvedOffset = offset * charIndex;
      anim.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(resolvedOffset);
  }
  ```

Proof:

[image: Rotating chars!]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer very clear. I was just wondering if it was easy to pause the animation after each loop for a second and then it starts again?